# Converting all tabs of excel sheet to PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pdf, win32com

I have an excel sheet having 2 tabs, first tab shows the summary of the second tab. I need to convert both the tabs to PDF format.

I used to below code

```
# converting xlsx to PDF
from win32com import client
import win32api
input_file = r'D:\DL-KBRB-Jan22-2.xlsx'
#give your file name with valid path 
output_file = r'D:\DL-KBRB-Jan22-2.pdf'
#give valid output file name and path
app = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
app.Interactive = False
app.Visible = False
Workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(input_file)
try:
    Workbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, output_file)
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to convert in PDF format.Please confirm environment meets all the requirements  and try again")
    print(str(e))
finally:
    Workbook.Close()
    app.Exit()
```

Problem with the above code is, it is converting only the first tab of the excel sheet to pdf but not the second tab. Not sure how to go about the same.
Also I'm getting the below error (though the PDF is converted)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-8d02b700e303> in <module>
     17 finally:
     18     Workbook.Close()
---> 19     app.Exit()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    525 
    526                 # no where else to look.
--> 527                 raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
    528 
    529         def __setattr__(self, attr, value):

AttributeError: Excel.Application.Exit
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be a Python solution, or will a VBA solution suffice?

Comment: @ASH it need not be a python solution, even VBA would help

Answer (score 1):

Using VBA, try it like this, for a used range on a sheet.

```
Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Consolidated.pdf", Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Or, if you want specific ranges, do it like this.

```
one = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10")
two = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B10")
three = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:B10")

    Worksheets(Array(one, two, three)).Select
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Consolidated.pdf", Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
         IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

one = ""
two = ""
three = ""
```